# asp.net mvc3 outputcache error

Tags: caching, asp.net-mvc-3

I've just updated a mvc 2 project to mvc 3 .
I have the following attribute on my controller:
    [OutputCache(NoStore =true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
this gives me the following exception :
Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

If I remove the attribute it's fine, but I need this attribute to prevent caching in this controller.

any ideas?

Comment: Is this for a partial view by any chance?  [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737556/asp-net-mvc2-error-in-view) a similar problem, maybe there are some clues there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute is no longer supported in MVC3

From [Scott Gu's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/10/announcing-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate-2.aspx)

> ASP.NET MVC 3’s output caching system
>   no longer requires you to specify a
>   VaryByParam property when declaring an
>   [OutputCache] attribute on a
>   Controller action method.  MVC3 now
>   automatically varies the output cached
>   entries when you have explicit
>   parameters on your action method –
>   allowing you to cleanly enable output
>   caching on actions using code like
>   below: